# Google maps API Overlap DirectionDisplay

Tags: google-api-java-client

I have a really specific question there...
I'am displaying when the site launch :

- 40 differents route in green

After that every two minutes i delete if actual route non-green exist and then load some other route but in specific color and i'd like these to be in front of the green one, but after exactly 3 load they are automaticly placed behind...

Hope was clear, thanks for your attention

Here's two picture to illustrate :

[When they aren't behind the green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXGWU.png)

[When they are behind the green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWn79.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        polylineOptions: {
            strokeColor: strokecolor,       // Color
            strokeOpacity: strokeopacity,   // Opacity
            strokeWeight: strokeweight,     // Weight
        },
```

TO :

```
        polylineOptions: {
            strokeColor: strokecolor,       // Color
            strokeOpacity: strokeopacity,   // Opacity
            strokeWeight: strokeweight,     // Weight
            zIndex: zindex                  // Priority display index
        },
```